# "Travel history" section is missing from Canada and USA applications?

Tags: visas, usa, canada

I'm trying to complete the [visitor application online](http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/e-services/account.asp) for a Canadian visa, but I can't find any section asking for my travel history. Do you think it has been removed from the process?

BTW, a friend applied for a USA visa recently, and he wasn't asked for his previous trips during his applying process. I was, when I applied for a USA visa 2 years ago.

Comment: I think this should be split into two separate questions, about US and Canada respectively.

Comment: I don't quite understand this question. You applied for a USA visa two years ago, and you were asked for your travel history. And now you are applying for a Canadian visa, and wondering why they don't ask the same questions? Why should they? They're different countries with different rules.

Comment: Please split this into two questions. Thank you.